# HotPlug.dll, dll call in Windows 7

Tags: dll, windows-7

From the objective of coding a call to set a drive for removal programmatically.  It is about to simply ask to set the drive in the removable state, as shown on drives in hardware properties, have it removed from logical drives, ...

What I know:
HotPlug.dll is the dll used by Windows to manage part of the drive removal

What I also get from Windows processes:

There is a function which display the message of a drive removed:
rundll32 hotplug,dll, ??messagefuncfion(=I don’t remember) (parameter: a guid from/to a pipe)...

What I get from the web, there are:
HotPlugEjectDevice
HotPlugEjectMedia
Functions in this dll ? Calling them don’t generate entry error

Question : how can I ask the system to set a drive for removal using this dll ?

I tried to embed the library in .net c# to get a bit more on the object model through wrapping but nothing.

I have tried to make calls like:

rundll32 hotplug.dll, HotPlugEjectDevice f:

rundll32 hotplug.dll, HotPlugEjectDevice \\.\PHYSICALDISK1
(and some other keys get from WMI data)

rundll32 hotplug.dll, HotPlugEjectDevice "f:"

rundll32 hotplug.dll, HotPlugEjectDevice "f:\"

rundll32 hotplug.dll, HotPlugEjectDevice 4
(Ref to order get from DiskPart)

.... Thanks before post

Comment: So, what is the actual problem?

Comment: [`CM_Request_Device_Eject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/cfgmgr32/nf-cfgmgr32-cm_request_device_ejectw).